# Most Efficient Tekkit Classic Mushroom Farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I want to make an automated mushroom farm in Tekkit classic. Note, I'm using the version *without* forestry. I can't find a very efficient way. The only farm I made work was a huge room with mushrooms in rows and block breakers a block away. When the mushroom spreads, it gets broken. The problem is that it only produces ~2 mushrooms/hour. I would like to know a way to get ~10 mushrooms/minute.

Also, if there's a mod which allows the changing of mushroom spread chances (Through fertilizer or something) for 1.2.5, I can use that instead.